# How to route messages by header value in Spring Integration 5.0.0.M3?

Tags: spring-integration

I used to route messages by a header (boolean) value in Spring Integration (before `5.0.0.M3`) with the help of a flow like this:

```java
    .<Boolean, HeaderValueRouter>
    route(new HeaderValueRouter(REGISTRATION_MODE__HEADER),
        routerSpec -> routerSpec
            .subFlowMapping(true  /* registering*/,
                f -> f.handle(String.class, /*some logic*/))
            .subFlowMapping(false /* unregistering */,
                f -> f.handle(String.class, /*some other logic*/)),
        endpointSpec -> endpointSpec.id("registrationRouter"))
```

But in `5.0.0.M3` this code became invalid because there is no `route` method with such signature anymore. The reason is clearly stated in *Java DSL breaking changes* chapter of [SI 4.3 to 5.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-4.3-to-5.0-Migration-Guide#java-dsl-breaking-changes):

> The `AbstractRouterSpec` now extends `ConsumerEndpointSpec` instead of
>   `MessageHandlerSpec` and, therefore, methods in the
>   `IntegrationFlowDefintion` like: ...
>   `route(R router, Consumer<RouterSpec<K, R>> routerConfigurer,
>          Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<R>> endpointConfigurer)`
>   ... have been removed in favor of those methods without the
>   `Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<?>>` since all its options are now
>   supported by the `AbstractRouterSpec` directly.

But the alternative is not clear. None of two current `route` methods accepting `AbstractMessageRouter` is capable of handling the new `routerConfigurer`. As a consequence, none of them can be configured with `subFlowMapping`.
Potential alternative - `route` methods accepting `Function` - is not applicable because those functions operate on *message payload* while I need to base routing decision on particular *message header*. Another similar solution might be to use `MessageProducerSpec` but I don't see how to combine it with `HeaderValueRouter`.

Is there a way to route messages with `HeaderValueRouter` and `subFlowMapping` at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest the `HeaderValueRouter` became obsolete when SpEL expressions has been added for support.

So, I suggest you do not hesitate to use a simple expression for this use-case:

```java
.route("headers." + REGISTRATION_MODE__HEADER,
        routerSpec -> routerSpec
                .subFlowMapping(true  /* registering*/,
                        f -> f.handle(String.class, /*some logic*/))
                .subFlowMapping(false /* unregistering */,
                        f -> f.handle(String.class, /*some other logic*/))
                .id("registrationRouter"))
```

Pay attention how is there is no one more `endpointSpec` argument, too.

Comment: Thank you Artem! That works. I wasn't a big fan of SpEL but it seems I should change my mind.
Perhaps the change I've encountered deserves a little bit more detailed explanation in 4.3->5.0 Migration Guide.

Comment: Well, that isn't a matter of Migration Guide. Perhaps we can mention that in the main Reference Manual. Please, raise a JIRA if you strongly feel it should be addressed.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I don't think it's a wide-spread problem so there is no need to clutter the main Reference Manual with it.